# images in Java JFrames

Tags: java

I am trying to make a basic guitar Tuner app that simply plays the appropriate audio file when a button is clicked. I am trying to place an image of a headstock of a guitar into the JFrame but am having a bit of trouble understanding the Oracle documentation for this. Could someone explain to me why my image isn't generating in this code?

p.s. I am aware that the bound's placement for the buttons are not set in any particular place and I know theres no audio code set. I wanted to place the buttons over the appropriate tuning peg on the headstock image first.

Thanks in advance for any tips or info here!

```
package guitartuner;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;


public class GuitarTuner extends JFrame{

private JFrame mainFrame;
private JLabel EJLabel, AJLabel, DJLabel, GJLabel, BJLabel, eJLabel, guitarJLabel,
        bassJLabel, loopJLabel;
private JPanel controlPanel;
private JButton EButton, AButton, DButton, GButton, BButton, eButton;

public class LoadImageApp extends Component{
    BufferedImage img;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public LoadImageApp(){
        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("headstock.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e){    
        }
    }
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
            return new Dimension(100,100);
        } else {
            return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
        }
    }
}

public GuitarTuner(){
    createUserInterface();
}

public void createUserInterface(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Guitar Tuner");

    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    f.add(new LoadImageApp());
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

    guitarJLabel = new JLabel();
    guitarJLabel.setBounds(16, 16, 90, 21);
    guitarJLabel.setText("Guitar");
    f.add(guitarJLabel);

    EButton = new JButton();
    EButton.setBounds(20, 20, 50, 50);
    EButton.setText("E");
    f.add(EButton);

    AButton = new JButton();
    AButton.setBounds(40, 40, 50, 50);
    AButton.setText("A");
    f.add(AButton);

    DButton = new JButton();
    DButton.setBounds(60, 60, 50, 50);
    DButton.setText("D");
    f.add(DButton);

    GButton = new JButton();
    GButton.setBounds(20, 100, 50, 50);
    GButton.setText("G");
    f.add(GButton);

    BButton = new JButton();
    BButton.setBounds(40, 100, 50, 50);
    BButton.setText("B");
    f.add(BButton);

    eButton = new JButton();
    eButton.setBounds(60, 100, 50, 50);
    eButton.setText("e");
    f.add(eButton);

    setTitle("Aaron's Awesome Guitar Tuner");
    setSize (500, 500);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GuitarTuner application = new GuitarTuner();
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a LayoutManager for your JFrame.Create and add all the components and then make the Frame visible.

```
public void createUserInterface(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Guitar Tuner");

    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    f.add(new LoadImageApp());
    //set LayoutManager
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    guitarJLabel = new JLabel();
    guitarJLabel.setBounds(16, 16, 90, 21);
    guitarJLabel.setText("Guitar");
    f.add(guitarJLabel);

    EButton = new JButton();
    EButton.setBounds(20, 20, 50, 50);
    EButton.setText("E");
    f.add(EButton);

    AButton = new JButton();
    AButton.setBounds(40, 40, 50, 50);
    AButton.setText("A");
    f.add(AButton);

    DButton = new JButton();
    DButton.setBounds(60, 60, 50, 50);
    DButton.setText("D");
    f.add(DButton);

    GButton = new JButton();
    GButton.setBounds(20, 100, 50, 50);
    GButton.setText("G");
    f.add(GButton);

    BButton = new JButton();
    BButton.setBounds(40, 100, 50, 50);
    BButton.setText("B");
    f.add(BButton);

    eButton = new JButton();
    eButton.setBounds(60, 100, 50, 50);
    eButton.setText("e");
    f.add(eButton);

    f.pack();
    f.setSize (500, 500);
    f.setTitle("Aaron's Awesome Guitar Tuner");
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

I have set FlowLayout,you can add any Layout based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand few things in code:

1. Why you are using two frames (GuitarTuner  and Frame f)
2. What is the purpose of class LoadImageApp (Is it just to draw a background image for the frame?)

If you just want to draw an image in the frame background than you can do it as below by setting a Layout Manager and Content pane (I have done it using a single frame):

```
        package guitartuner;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;


    public class GuitarTuner extends JFrame {

        private JLabel guitarJLabel;
        private JButton EButton, AButton;

        public GuitarTuner() {
            createUserInterface();
        }

        public void createUserInterface() {

            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(final WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("headstock.jpg")));
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            this.guitarJLabel = new JLabel();
            this.guitarJLabel.setBounds(16, 16, 90, 21);
            this.guitarJLabel.setText("Guitar");
            add(this.guitarJLabel);

            this.EButton = new JButton();
            this.EButton.setBounds(20, 20, 50, 50);
            this.EButton.setText("E");
            add(this.EButton);

            this.AButton = new JButton();
            this.AButton.setBounds(40, 40, 50, 50);
            this.AButton.setText("A");
            add(this.AButton);

            setTitle("Aaron's Awesome Guitar Tuner");
            setSize(500, 500);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            GuitarTuner application = new GuitarTuner();
            application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }
```